# Explanation of random forest performance difference to when using categories and when using dummy variables

Tags: classification, feature-selection, random-forest, decision-trees, feature-engineering

I have some hand coded feature which is a category with values "High", "Low", and "Normal".

I created this feature myself and my problem performance (classification) increased dramatically when using it with expanding these by dummy variables.

Now since I'm trying random forest, I thought I change "High, Low, Normal" to 1, -1, 0 instead.

Now the same model doesn't learn at all.

I thought it should become easier actually for it to split.
Does this have to do with me putting normal to 0?

Thank you for any explanation helping me to understand this.

Comment: Should not happen. Can you share the code

Comment: Sure, which part? It's fairly large

Comment: edit: but if you are sure, I was too that that shouldn't happen. So I may have just have a bug somewhere and look for it

Comment: how were "high", "low", "normal" encoded in the first place?

Comment: @NikosM. I defined a basic threshold function
def foo(x) if x > a: return "high" elif x < b return "low" else return "normal. Like that. And I just replaced high, low, normal with 1, -1, 0 for numerical encoding

Comment: What do you mean by "expanding these by dummy variables"? Why and how?

Comment: @Erwan one hot encoding i.e. indicator variables for each category, pd.dummies(X)

Comment: You removed this one-hot-encoding step when switching to numerical values right?

Comment: @Erwan yes of course. I thought I'd help it this way by having fewer columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work: the variable is ordinal so using numerical values makes sense.

So there's a bug somewhere, here are a few suggestions of things to look at:

- Possibly a type conversion error somewhere: make sure the variable is interpreted as numerical.
- Check whether the model actually uses the variable: if not then it's likely some type error; if yes then I would investigate what goes wrong: for example it might help to plot this variable vs. target in the two cases where the variable is categorical or numerical.
- Maybe some difference between the preprocessing of the training and test set: apply the model on the training set, if the performance is good then it's likely that there's something wrong in the preprocessing of the test set.

Comment: Thank you Erwan, I'll try out your suggestions to find the bug.
I have been looking for one since yesterday, this may help me narrow it down. Cheers, Oli

Comment: @Oliver hope it helps but I probably didn't cover everything, these are just a few thoughts off the top of my head. You can edit the question to add more detail in case you don't find the issue.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks!